# command not found: __start_kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, zsh, kubectl, zsh-completion

I installed kubectl and tried enable shell autocompletion for zsh.
When I'm using `kubectl` autocompletion works fine. Howewer when I'm trying use autocompletion with alias `k` then shell return me

```
k g...(eval):1: command not found: __start_kubectl                                                                                                                            8:45 
(eval):1: command not found: __start_kubectl
(eval):1: command not found: __start_kubectl
```

In my `.zshrc` file I have:

```
source <(kubectl completion zsh)
alias k=kubectl
compdef __start_kubectl k
```

Comment: Before sourcing the zsh completion scripts, have you added `autoload -U +X compinit && compinit` to your .zshrc?

Comment: I haven't added `autoload -U +X compinit && compinit`, however when I did it now, it didn't help

Answer (score 2):

If you use Oh My Zsh, what fixed it for me was updating:

```
omz update

... lots of output

source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: this solved for me

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one:

```
compdef _kubectl k
```

Comment: After execute `compdef _kubectl k` and input `k g` and pres tab, shell return me
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
```o matches: `completions' or `filename'```

Answer (score 1):

add the following to the beginning of your ~/.zshrc file:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

then restart your terminal.

Comment: I added but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands:

```
kubectl completion zsh > "${fpath[1]}/_kubectl"
ln -s "${fpath[1]}/_kubectl" "${fpath[1]}/_k"
```

First command will create the auto-load for `kubectl` and the second one is a link to the first one but with alias `k`.

Now remove your completion configuration from your `.zshrc` related to `k` or `kubectl`. The only configuration you need is `alias k=kubectl`.

Alternatively you can get the list of paths where completions are search with `echo $fpath` and choose one of those directories as target of previous commands, such as:

```
kubectl completion zsh > "/usr/share/zsh/vendor-functions"
ln -s "/usr/share/zsh/vendor-functions/_kubectl" "/usr/share/zsh/vendor-functions/_k"
```